# Casperjs error - invalid syntax error

Tags: centos, phantomjs, casperjs

I recently installed Casperjs on server (centos) and when I try to run I get the following error:

```
 File "/usr/local/bin/casperjs", line 11
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

This is the result of running "casperjs --version" which should just print the version number. Although any other commands with casperjs also give the same output.

The steps that I followed to install are pretty standard:

```
git clone git://github.com/n1k0/casperjs.git
cd casperjs
git checkout tags/1.0.2
ln -sf `pwd`/bin/casperjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs
```

Also, I'm running version 1.9.6 of phantomjs which is required for casperjs.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is you version of python?

Comment: Python version is 2.4.3

Comment: I'm on v2.7.3 and don't have this issue.

Comment: Is it okay to upgrade the version? I've heard that upgrading can break yum since 2.4 is a dependency....

Answer (score 0):

You could check if  the version of python is greater than 2.6 or not 
for my case , I type the command

python -v

and I get 2.4.3 on the old online redhat machine .

than you could try update your python version . 
It might some help